# Creating a JQuery Slideshow of a Background-Image

Tags: jquery

I have an element that serves as the banner on my website. This banner has HTML content on it, but uses a high-resolution picture as the background-image. Because of this, I'm loading the background-image last and fading it in when it has been downloaded. My code looks like this:

```
<table id="bannerTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:640px; height:480px;">
  <tr><td style="padding-top:20px; padding-left:300px;">
    <div>[Some Text]</div>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <div>[Site Menu Goes Here]</div>
  </td></tr>
</table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#bannerTable").loadBGImage("/picture1.png");
    });

    $.fn.loadBGImage = function (url) {
      var t = this;
      $('<img />')
        .attr('src', url)
        .load(function () {
          t.each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + url + ')');
            $(this).fadeIn();
          });
        });
      return this;
    }
  </script>
```

Even with this, my website feels static. Because of this, I want to loop through multiple high-resolution images at runtime. These high-resolution images will be used in the bannerTable as the background-image. I want them to fade-in and fade-out as they loop.

How do I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/creating-a-jquery-slideshow-of-a-background-image

look the demo source for the full working code

Answer (score 0):

Basically use `setInterval` to call loadBGImage, say every 60 seconds.

e.g. something like

```
var interval = 0;
var intervalTimer = setInterval(
    function(){
        if (++interval > 10) {interval = 1}
        $("#bannerTable").loadBGImage("/picture" + interval + ".png");
    }
    ,
    60000
);
```