# Background image JQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, background-image

I'm trying to do a background image slideshow using JQuery.
I found an interesting example here:
[Creating a JQuery Slideshow of a Background-Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950804/creating-a-jquery-slideshow-of-a-background-image/6176927#6176927)

That is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#bannerTable").loadBGImage();
    setInterval('$("#bannerTable").loadBGImage()', 5000);
});

$.fn.loadBGImage = function() {
    var images = ["home_photo_welshboy.jpg", "home_photo_jam343.jpg", "home_photo_xdjio.jpg", "home_photo_ccgd.jpg"];
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    return this.each(function() {
        var $obj = $(this);
        $obj.fadeOut(500,function() {
            $obj.css('background', 'url(http://l.yimg.com/g/images/' + image + ')').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
}
```

There are a few things I want to change, which I can't seem to get my head around.
Firstly, I'd like the slideshow to load the next image, not a random image. Secondly, I need the child elements of the div to be visible at all times and not fade with the parent.

Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. But the size of the main div is 770 x 350px. The most important thing, though, is the next image feature.

Comment: I want it to change automatically.

Comment: can you put link here you working on to help you more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way : Create a global variable.

```
var currentPic = 0;
$(function() {
    $("#bannerTable").loadBGImage();
    setInterval('$("#bannerTable").loadBGImage()', 5000);
});

$.fn.loadBGImage = function() {
    var images = ["home_photo_welshboy.jpg", "home_photo_jam343.jpg", "home_photo_xdjio.jpg", "home_photo_ccgd.jpg"];
    var image = images[currentPic];
    currentPic = (currentPic+1)%images.length; //loop once you reach last pic.
    [...]
```

Secondly, it is simply impossible to have a child visible while a parent is hidden. Take the example :

```
<div style="display:none">hide me<span style="display:block">show me</span></div>
```

The child will be hidden, since it is **inside** the parent. To fix this, you could make them siblings within a new parent (`<div><div /><span /></div>`).