# Background image slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I just discovered the CSS3 `background-size:cover` attribute. Now I would like to replace this background image by a slideshow (e.g. jQuery cycle), without losing the automatic scaling done by the browser. Is there a simple solution for this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951990/1205935) answer, which probably contains a solution, but I am not quite sure how to adjust it. I tried to copy and paste the code below, but nothing cycles...

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#home").loadBGImage();
        setInterval('$("#home").loadBGImage()', 5000); 
    });

    $.fn.loadBGImage = function() {
        var images = ["background1.jpg",
        "background2.jpg",
        "background3.jpg",
        "background4.jpg" ];

        var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

        return this.each(function() {
            var $obj = $(this);
            $obj.fadeOut(500,function() {
                $obj.css('background', 'url(../images/' + image + ')')
                    .fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in console?

Comment: Tools > Web Developer > Error Console or user shortcut Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: Thanks. I get that $ is not a function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay than the problem is you have used jQuery.noConflict(); So in that case all $ must be replaced with jQuery, like below

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#home").loadBGImage();
    setInterval('jQuery("#home").loadBGImage()', 5000); 
 });

 jQuery.fn.loadBGImage = function() {
    var images = ["background1.jpg",
    "background2.jpg",
    "background3.jpg",
    "background4.jpg" ];

    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    return this.each(function() {
        var $obj = jQuery(this);
        $obj.fadeOut(500,function() {
            $obj.css('background', 'url(../images/' + image + ')').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
 };

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by replacing all $ with jQuery? All? I have been using $'s with other jQuery scripts as above, without having to replace $ by anything else...

Comment: This is because in the code you used jQuery.noConflict(); and it used when two or more files of jquery been conflicted. If you are referencing single file of jquery min than remove the noConflict and it will work as expected.